# Lossless extraction of audio from .webm and .mp4 files

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg

To extract audio from a **.webm** file, using the **ffmpeg** tool:

`ffmpeg -i "input.webm" -acodec copy "output.opus"`

The command above works perfectly, however it extracts only one file at the time. What would be a command to extract all .webm files in specific directory, keeping the original names of the files and only changing the file extension from .webm to .opus? I also need to extract .aac audio from .mp4 files using ffmpeg. What would be the proper command for that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, Superuser works best if you only ask one question per Question post. Can you edit your Question post down to a single question?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
for %a in (*.mp4 *.webm) do if "%~xa"==".webm" (ffmpeg -i "%a" -acodec copy "%~na.opus") else (ffmpeg -i "%a" -acodec copy "%~na.aac")
```

To do each type individually:

mp4:

```
for %a in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%a" -acodec copy "%~na.aac"
```

webm:

```
for %a in (*.webm) do ffmpeg -i "%a" -acodec copy "%~na.opus"
```

Comment: Thank you. The .mp4 and .webm files are in a separate directories, so I would prefer to extract one file type at the time. Are the commands below correct?___1. webm to opus: for %a in (*.webm) do if "%~xa"==".webm" (ffmpeg -i "%a" -acodec copy "%~na.opus") ___2. mp4 to aac: for %a in (*.mp4) do if "%~xa"==".mp4" (ffmpeg -i "%a" -acodec copy "%~na.aac")

Comment: Please see updated answer....